# How to disable validation before calling UpdateModel in MVC3 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, updatemodel

I'm looking to enable "saving" of form data prior to submission.

I want users to be able to save form progress, even when the form is in an invalid state, and then come back to it at a later time.

Now, my only problem is that I want to be able to use `UpdateModel` method to update my model. However, as the form is potentially invalid or just partially complete, this will throw an error.

Is there a way to annotate the following method such that validation is ignored in the **SAVE** instance?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Model values)
{
var model = new Model();
UpdateModel(model);
}
```

I want to save having to write a 1-1 mapping for the elements being saved - which is my fallback option, but isn't very maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `TryUpdateModel(model)` a try, should fit your needs.

This won't throw an exception, **and it will** update the model and then return `false` if there are validation errors.

If you care about the errors, you check the `ModelState` in the false instance.

Hence, you can use it as so to always save changes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Model values)
{
var model = new Model();
TryUpdateModel(model);

model.saveChanges();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Initially I thought TryUpdateModel(model) just returned false and did nothing. HOWEVER, it does still update the model. That was the part I was missing. Essentially, I want to suppress any validation errors, and now I can do that by just ignoring the return value from TryUpdateModel. Perfect!

Comment: Be aware, if you have client-side validation enabled, then you won't be able to submit the form.  You could, however, disable the validation prior to submitting in a "Save" button.

Comment: @MystereMan - That's what I've already implemented. I simply do a form submission via ajax, and I can provide some visual feedback based on the response. This makes sure to ignore client-side validation, and allows saving of the form extremely simply. Validation will occur before any of the data is actually used, and any attempts at injection can be tested against.